# wfastcgi-enable it show 'Ensure your user has sufficient privileges and try again.'

Tags: python, django, iis, command-prompt, wfastcgi

I want to deploy my django website in window server 2008 by follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CpFU16KrJcQ&t=191s

In step wfastcgi-enable it show message like this.

command prompt

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.0.6002]
Copyright (c) 2006 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Administrator>wfastcgi-enable
ERROR ( message:Unknown attribute "signalBeforeTerminateSeconds". )
An error occurred running the command:

['C:\\Windows\\system32\\inetsrv\\appcmd.exe', 'set', 'config', '/section:system
.webServer/fastCGI', "/+[fullPath='c:\\users\\administrator\\appdata\\local\\pro
grams\\python\\python37\\python.exe', arguments='c:\\users\\administrator\\appda
ta\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\wfastcgi.py', signalB
eforeTerminateSeconds='30']"]

Ensure your user has sufficient privileges and try again.

C:\Users\Administrator>
```

Comment: Seems like an issue with user privileges. Maybe you 've set things up to a folder that requires admin rights?

Comment: Yes i guess. wfastcgi folder are here
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py

Comment: You need to open Powershell as an administrator: https://gist.github.com/bparaj/ac8dd5c35a15a7633a268e668f4d2c94

Comment: I run as an adminstrator but nothing change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it now.
Becuase in IIS 7.0  didn't have signalBeforeTerminateSeconds like IIS 7.5

The  element of the  collection was updated in IIS 7.5 with the monitorChangesTo, stderrMode, and signalBeforeTerminateSeconds attributes.

So I install my new window server version to solve this.